# Open FDF document on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, safari, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I'm having the issue documented here:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/445594

When I try to open a FDF, I just get a pop up over and over again which asks me if I want to open the form.

One possible solution is downgrading to Safari 3, but that is not proven to work.

I thought maybe I could get the FDF to open in FireFox, but changing the default browser does not affect Reader, it still attempts to open the FDF in Safari (strange).

So, does anyone know of a way to open this form?

Thanks

-Corey

Answer (score 1):

On snow leopard you have to set Safari to 32 bit mode or use Firefox (set to run under Rosetta) to successfully open fdf files in Acrobat Reader.  Additionally if the server sending the fdf does not send a header with a file name ending in .fdf it will display blank or simply save it as a .pdf, .asp page etc dependant on the server platform.

Answer (score -1):

You can try saving it and using Preview to open it. Preview has proven very versatile for me, and if you are running **10.6** its even better.